# Does updating statistics in SQL Server refreshes the data pages previously cached?

Tags: sql-server, caching, statistics

Since during the process of updating statistics, the SQL Server accesses the underlying data pages, does this process also update the data previously cached in RAM?  Just to be clear, I am NOT talking about the procedure/query plan cache, I am talking about the actual data pages.

Comment: The data pages used by stats update (and most SQL data access) are always in memory. It's by happenstance whether they needed to be read from storage into buffer cache to be used.

Comment: Thank you, Dan! In other words, whatever data had been previously cached in the SQL Server memory, will REMAIN in memory after the update statistics ran. Additional data pages read by the update statistics will be added. However, in cases of high memory pressure, wouldn't at least some of the previously cached pages get flushed to disk as a result?

Comment: Only dirty (modified) pages get flushed to disk and will remain in cache afterwards. Buffer cache entries are reused on a least recently used basis so the most active pages will remain in memory.